# AWS - EC2 and S3 with programmatically uploading files has wrong ownership/permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I have a S3 bucket, and an EC2 instance.

I am programmatically uploading from my machine to S3 using code from the Amazon web site [put_objec t](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/cpp-s3-put_object.cpp.html). The files appear in the AWS S3 web interface.

I have then edited `/etc/fstab` on my EC2 instance as follows.

```
s3fs#xxxx /home/xxxx fuse _netdev,allow_other 0 0
```

And the bucket appears in the file system - But the permissions is drwxr----- and the owner/group is both root. I am trying to run my own processes under a different user on EC2 and monitor these uploaded files. Uninformatively this is causing problems due to the ownership/group/file permissions and therefore unable to access these uploaded files.

Is there a way to make the owner/group some other user and also to change the permissions during performing the upload to S3.

Comment: The upload to S3 has probably very little / absolutely nothing to do with how they are displayed in s3fs. Sounds like a purely s3fs focused question.

Comment: I think that adding `,rw` to the end of your options might solve the problem. But `man fstab` is the place to start.

Comment: Which version of s3fs do you use?  1.85 and later should default to 0750 or 0640 if there is no `x-amz-meta-mode` or similar header.

Comment: @AndrewGaul - It is defaulting to 0750 and is the latest version. Would prefer 0755/0644 for dirs/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3fs#bucket /path -o umask=0002` should add group write and everyone read/execute to all files.

Comment: I also added `uid` and `gid` options as well